# Compare two arrays and at same value index change data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've an array like this:

```
    array1 = ["Jan","Feb",....,"Dec"];
    array2 = ["Jan","Sep"];
```

Now compare both and at `array1[0]` and `array1[8]` values changed to `0`.

I want output:

```
    array1 = [0, "Feb", "March", ..., 0, "Oct", ..., "Dec"]
```

Comment: huh????????????

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As it is, it is hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: If we compare this two array , index 0 and 8 of array1 is equal to array2, then change the value of that indexes with new values in array1. my new array1 = [0, "Feb", "March", ..., 0, "Oct",... , "Dec"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but assuming you want to change the array1 values to 0, if they are contained in array2, you could do this:

```js
array1 = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
array2 = ["Jan","Sep"];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array2.includes(array1[i])) {
        array1[i] = 0;
    }
}

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: I have an another problems, array1, array2 are same and there is an array3 is same length as array2, now how to set array3 value to array1 instead of 0 .

Comment: @VinitBhavsar It would be similar to this answer, but instead of setting the array item to 0, you would set it like this: `array1[i]  = array3[i];`